# How to write a Splunk query to count response codes of multiple endpoints

Tags: api, splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to monitor performance/metrics of my application as an external system is going through a heavy data ingest. Currently, I can easily watch one endpoint using the following

```
index=my_index environment=prod service=myservice api/myApi1 USER=user1 earliest=07/19/2021:12:00:00 | stats count by RESPONSECODE
```

How can I adjust this query to include the additional endpoints I'd like to monitor? Ultimately I'd like a pie chart showing the total numbers of successes and failures across this API for the user.

Thanks all!

Edit: In the above query, api/myApi1 is the field I'm referring to. How can I include additional api/myApi# endpoints properly?

Answer (score 1):

Include additional endpoints by adding them to the base query or by making the base query less specific.

```
index=my_index environment=prod service=myservice api/myApi1 USER IN (user1 user2 user3) earliest=07/19/2021:12:00:00 
| stats count by USER, RESPONSECODE
```

OR

```
index=my_index environment=prod service=myservice api/myApi1 USER=* earliest=07/19/2021:12:00:00 
| stats count by USER, RESPONSECODE
```

Comment: you look to be expanding the scope of users. My question is regarding including additional endpoints, e.g. api/myApi1, api/myApi2, etc.

Comment: You didn't specify how an endpoint is identified so I chose a field.  Feel free to choose another one (perhaps `host`).  The method is the same.

Comment: Right that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work. api/myApi1 one is the portion I'd like to extend to include additional endpoints. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: This should help. It extracts the api name then groups on it.
`index=my_index environment=prod service=myservice api/* USER=* earliest=07/19/2021:12:00:00 
| rex "api\/(?<api>\S+)"
| stats count by api, RESPONSECODE`